# goog is not defined error while trying to use Protocol Buffers - Google's data interchange format

Tags: node.js, module, npm, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Protocol Buffers - Google's data interchange format referring https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/js

I tried to follow documentation  i am able to get the setup of  Protocol Compiler and able to do

```
 protoc --js_out=library=myproto_libs,binary:. messages.proto
```

but when i do npm install google-protobuf i am getting

```
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/google-
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'google-protobuf' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

and if i write the sample which can use that generated binary it says goog is not defined

```
goog.require('com.nec.eva.msap.proto.alerts.FaceAlert');
var message = com.nec.eva.msap.proto.alerts.FaceAlert();
message.watchlist_id("1");
message.candidate_id("25");
message.gender("female");
bytes = message.serializeBinary();
```

I am not sure why i am not able to do npm install and also how that goog.require('com.nec.eva.msap.proto.alerts.FaceAlert'); will use the generated binary please help i have almost spent a day to understand but not getting it

Answer (score 3):

There are issues and

> the API is [not well-documented](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/js) yet

You need to compile it with `protoc messages.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:.`

Or set

```js
var jspb = require('google-protobuf')
var goog = jspb
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to search on http://node-modules.com/search?q=protocol+buffers.  This one is popular and should work: https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `google-protobuf` is not in the npm repository, so installing it will not work (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf). However, there are a number of protocol buffers libraries that you could try:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-buffers this one plays a bit fast and loose, but is really good for many simple cases (and it's blindingly fast).
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs aims to be a bit more complete; I haven't personally used this one, but it's well regarded and has a large number of downloads.

Comment: can u please say what is that goog referees in documentation

Comment: and also please say what is the difference between serializeBinary and encode ie, why one should be used

Comment: For anyone coming across this  question now, this appears to have changed since this answer was written. There is a `google-protobuf` package, which the link in the answer now routes to, and it is explicitly referenced in Google's own javascript protobuf repo: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/js#protocol-buffers---googles-data-interchange-format .