# `goog is not defined`

Tags: javascript, react-native, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf to serialize/deserialize the data in my react native project. I have used closure imports which require the syntax 
`goog.require('proto.my.package.Message')`.
I see this error `goog is not defined` when I run the app.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code?

Comment: Make sure you have this package installed and defined in your code.

Comment: How are you importing the closure library? The 'goog' variable is defined there, so you'll need to pull it in via a script tag like "<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>" or through an npm package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61439886/2655092